# no healthy upstream after login in kubeflow

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubeflow

I installed kubeflow
just followed https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/tree/master install guide

here is my pods
[pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBx9C.jpg)

Wehen I run this command

> kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system 8080:80

Dex logo site is shown.

I entered username to user@example.com
and password to 12341234 that guided from github

but I got
[no healthy upstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72gHQ.png)

How can I solve this?

I uninstalled minikube and kubectl and resintalled

Comment: having same issue, any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

Pods such as the Central Dashboard are showing `ImagePullBackOff` or `ErrImagePull` errors, suggesting problems pulling images. Debug with `kubectl describe pod -n kubeflow {pod_name}` or `kubectl get events -n kubeflow --sort-by='.lastTimestamp'` to identify troublesome images. These may be related to pulling a Kubeflow component or an Istio sidecar image. Additionally, Docker Hub's rate limit for anonymous users ([Docker Hub Rate Limit](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/)) might be a factor.